# Android Wear RemoteControlClient add Like Button

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am developing an App that has a lock screen widget where it has a play, pause, prev and next. When I connect my phone to an Android wear, it automatically shows this buttons and it works fine. I would like to add a "Like" button that would automatically be shown on the lock screen and the android wear. I know that I can create a Notification and add action for the like. But I want to know if is it possible to achieve that using only RemoteControlClient?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using rating with the flag `FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_RATING` ? It seems that it's the only way to maintain generic methods and avoid having to set custom code on the wear side (or through notifications).

This flag can be set with `setTransportControlFlags`

> Flag indicating a RemoteControlClient supports ratings. This flag must
>   be set in order for components that display the RemoteControlClient
>   information, to display ratings information, and, if ratings are
>   declared editable (by calling addEditableKey(int) with the
>   RATING_KEY_BY_USER key), it will enable the user to rate the media,
>   with values being received through the interface set with
>   setMetadataUpdateListener(OnMetadataUpdateListener).

Unfortunately, few or not example exists on the web. I discovered only one (unanswered) question relative to this on SO :
[Android 4.4 KitKat Rating API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613471/android-4-4-kitkat-rating-api)

Comment: By only setting the flag, the rating should appear on the lock screen or the android wear right? Well it didn't.